# Filing a motion - does it have to be signed?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, georgia

If a lawyer wants to file a motion on behalf of his client in criminal case, does the motion have to be signed by client? by the lawyer? both? If so, can it be done electroncially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motions are generally signed by the lawyer for the client in a criminal case, not by the client, or made orally by the lawyer on the record in open court. Oral motions are the rule rather than the exception in criminal cases.

There are a handful of filings, such as a plea of guilty, which must be approved by a client and are usually accepted, in person, with an oral statement of the client, in open court, after the judge recites information giving the client informed consent before making the statement in open court.

Affidavits and declarations of fact of client would often have to be signed by a client in a criminal case, but these are very rare in criminal cases, even though they are common in civil cases.

E-filing in Georgia courts is a moving target, as illustrated by [the linked table](https://georgiacourts.gov/efile-court-records/) for civil case e-filing requirements that differ from court to court and county to county within the state, and changes on a regular basis as new courts are converted to efiling.

In courts which have e-filing for criminal cases, the wet ink signature of the lawyer does not have to be submitted to the court, although sometimes the lawyer has to keep a wet ink signature version on file in their office. The exact mechanics of signatures of motions that are e-filed are typically established by a third-party e-filing vendor for the state, and then adopted as court rules.

In a federal criminal case, this is governed by Federal Rule Of Criminal Procedure 49(b)(4) which states:

> *Signature.* Every written motion and other paper must be signed by at least one attorney of record in the attorney’s name—or by a person
> filing a paper if the person is not represented by an attorney. The
> paper must state the signer’s address, e-mail address, and telephone
> number. Unless a rule or statute specifically states otherwise, a
> pleading need not be verified or accompanied by an affidavit. The
> court must strike an unsigned paper unless the omission is promptly
> corrected after being called to the attorney’s or person’s attention.

Answer (score 1):

### Depends on the jurisdiction and the specific court

Criminal (and civil) procedures vary by jurisdiction. In some jurisdictions, they will need wet-ink signatures; in others, they have to be electronic; or either; or not signed at all.

Comment: What about the state of Georgia?

Comment: I’ve heard it’s nice, never been there.

Comment: In the state of Georgia, who has to sign a motion? Does it have to be a wet-ink signature?